# Rails + Postgres: Not returning timezone info on column from joined table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

Events have many shifts.

My shifts table which contains a `starts_at` and `ends_at` column which are DATETIME format.

If I query the shifts table, the `starts_at` and `ends_at` columns return a string which contains timezone information and is recognised by Rails as an `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` object -- and I can manipulate it accordingly.

If I include the `shifts.starts_at` or `shifts.ends_at` column in a more complex query involving a join, I seem to be losing the timezone info in the result set. Consider the following query:

```
SELECT events.id, events.name, events.default_shift_start,
shifts.id AS shift_id, shifts.starts_at, shifts.ends_at, users.id AS user_id,
users.first_name, users.last_name 
FROM "events" 
INNER JOIN "shifts" ON "shifts"."event_id" = "events"."id" 
INNER JOIN "requests" ON "requests"."shift_id" = "shifts"."id" 
INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "requests"."user_id" 
WHERE (events.default_shift_start > '2012-08-22 05:55:22.069340' AND requests.status = 'accepted') 
ORDER BY default_shift_start ASC
```

**EDIT: I'm calling this query in Rails by way of:**

```
Event.joins(:shifts => { :requests => :user}).where(["events.default_shift_start > ? AND requests.status = ?", Time.now, "accepted"]).select("events.id, events.name, events.default_shift_start, shifts.id AS shift_id, shifts.starts_at, shifts.ends_at, users.id AS user_id, users.first_name, users.last_name").order("default_shift_start ASC")
```

Produces:

```
+-----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id  | shift_id | starts_at           | ends_at             |
+-----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
| 17  | 80       | 2012-08-23 00:30:00 | 2012-08-23 07:30:00 |
| 17  | 55       | 2012-08-23 00:30:00 | 2012-08-23 07:30:00 |
+-----+----------+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The issue is that the columns from the JOINed table (`shifts`) aren't returning any timezone data, causing Rails to recognize them as String data. The data is stored in the database as UTC. If I include a `datetime` column from the `events` table in the same query, it includes timezone data in the result.

I've been searching through the documentation trying to understand what's going on here, but to no avail.

Comment: Please show your table definitions, either `CREATE TABLE` statements or the output of `\d tablename` in psql. Is it possible that you're using a mix of `timestamp` and `timestamptz` types, and Rails only likes one of them?

Comment: @CraigRinger: Rails implies `timestamp without time zone` and UTC values in the database.

Comment: Table definitions [here](https://gist.github.com/3424581) as requested. The columns are `timestamp without timezone` format -- this does indeed seem to be a Rails issue, as opposed to a Postgres one. For some reason, the column selected from the JOINed table isn't being recognised as a the usual type. Note that if I select from the shifts table directly, I have no such problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you should start with getting a grasp on the involved data types. The "datetime" data type in PostgreSQL is actually [`timestamp` and there are two variants: `with` and `without time zone`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-datetime.html). The default is `without`.

Internally, PostgreSQL always stores a UTC timestamp. Time zone data itself is *not* saved at all with timestamps, neither with nor without time zone. Those are just decorators for input and output that accommodate for the timezone setting of the client.

Find a more [detailed explanation, examples and links at this related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9576170/939860).

Comment: Thanks, Erwin. I'm presently working around the issue by converting the resulting `String` using `to_time` in Rails. I'm convinced that this is a Railsism, to do with the fact that the joined column (from the `shifts` table) doesn't exist in the schema of the object I'm using to query (`Event`).

Answer (score 0):

i think if you put starts_at::timestamptz then you are good.

Comment: my guess is that you ask events to give u timestamptz by default, but since in your query you do a comparision via string, it converted the column into string. try '2012-08-22 05:55:22.069340'::timestamp as well.

Comment: It does indeed return timezone data in the result - but Rails still presents it as a `String`. Again, thinking more and more that this is because Rails can't find `starts_at` column in the schema for the `events` table (because it is a column from the `shifts` table being accessed by a JOIN). Don't know if this is a "bug" or not, but I guess I have to work around it or look at the Rails codebase to see if its an issue there.